# Can I assume `node` is always in the $PATH setup by NPM?

Tags: node.js, windows, cross-platform

So I have have been using NPM as a simple build tool for a few years where I can assume that every CLI tool installed through `package.json` is available in the `PATH`, as NPM adds the `./node_modules/.bin` path to it.

But as I was about to write a small Node script to do some house cleanup chores I got a bit wary if NPM actually has the `node` executable in the PATH it gives to users. This might seems stupid, as all the scripts in `./node_modules/.bin` rely on `node` being there for the wrapper scripts on Unix to be able to find it, but I thought there might be some magic going on *in Windows*. Perhaps they use some other magic of their own. Or something. Does not matter, really, I just want to be able to assert:

*Is the `node` executable always on the `PATH` given to npm scripts by `NPM`? On all platforms? And is it always the same Node as NPM runs on?*

This might seem too basic to almost be asked, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: not a definitive answer, but too lengthy for a comment

If you look at the documentation on [default values](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values) that are set up for scripts:

> npm will default some script values based on package contents.
>
> "start": "node server.js":
>
> If there is a server.js file in the root of your package, then npm
>   will default the start command to **node server.js**.

Although this isn't a definitive answer to your question, npm uses `node` as a default in case there's no `npm start` defined. This is a clear indicator npm relies on node to be present under all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can safely make the assumption that npm requires node to be in the PATH, or in the same folder as npm. This is from `npm.cmd` (the script that is called when you type npm):

```
SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)
```